# How to handle missing data in calculation of new column using awk?

Tags: unix, awk

I want to add a new column with values equal to `-log` of values in the `3rd` column. But, there are fields filled with `NA`. I used the below code that as expected outputs `inf` for these fields.

```
awk 'NR!=1 {print $1, $2, $3, -1*(log($3))}' File

File

1   rs3    0.341
2   rs4    NA
3   rs5    0.599
4   rs6    NA

Desired output 
                   NEW COLUMN   
1   rs3    0.341   1.074
2   rs4    NA      NA
3   rs5    0.599   0.512   
4   rs6    NA      NA
```

How can I keep `NA` in the new column?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see a tenth column in the input to take the log of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two print statements: if column 3 is great than zero print the log otherwise print the original value.

```
awk '$3 + 0.0 != 0.0 {print $1, $2, -1*(log($3)) } 
$3 + 0.0 == 0.0 {print $1, $2, $3 }' File
```